# How do I improve Searching in an AutoComplete text widget

Tags: android, sqlite, search, autocompletetextview

I have two AutoCompleteTextViews that are populated with data from sqlite database. I pull information from an ERP Server and store it locally in the sqlite database and populate the textview like in this:

```
equipment = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.equipmentAutoCompleteTextView);
    if(equipment.getText().toString().length() == 0){
        equipment.setError("Equipment is required");
    }
    FieldInstallationDB sqlitedb1 = new FieldInstallationDB(this);
    sqlitedb1.openForRead();

    String[] items = sqlitedb.getAllItemNames();

    for(int i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
    {
        Log.i(this.toString(), items[i]);
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, items);
    equipment.setAdapter(adapter1);
    equipment.setThreshold(1);
```

And here:

```
customerName = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.customerNameAutoCompleteTextView);
    if(customerName.getText().toString().length() == 0){
        customerName.setError("Customer Name is required");
    }
    FieldInstallationDB sqlitedb = new FieldInstallationDB(this);
    sqlitedb.openForRead();

    String[] accounts = sqlitedb.getAllCustNames();

    for(int i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++)
    {
        Log.i(this.toString(), accounts[i]);
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, accounts);
    customerName.setAdapter(adapter);
    customerName.setThreshold(1);
```

Assuming I have these:

- Black Spoon
- Red Spoon
- Spoonful

And I start typying "spo", I want to see all three items listed to make a selection. Instead, I get only "Spoonful" coming up. How do I get it to recognise and display all instances(items) that have the letters "spo"?

**UPDATE:**

After the first comment to my question, I read more articles and updated my code to look like this:

```
equipment = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.equipmentAutoCompleteTextView);
    if(equipment.getText().toString().length() == 0){
        equipment.setError("Equipment is required");
    }
    FieldInstallationDB sqlitedb1 = new FieldInstallationDB(this);
    sqlitedb1.openForRead();

    String[] items = sqlitedb1.getAllItemNames();

    for(int i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
    {
        Log.i(this.toString(), items[i]);
    }

    equipment.setThreshold(1);


    SimpleCursorAdapter itemNameAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, null, items, toView, 0);



    itemNameAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {

        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
            return suggestItemCompletions(constraint);
        }
    });

itemNameAdapter.setCursorToStringConverter(new SimpleCursorAdapter.CursorToStringConverter() {
        public CharSequence convertToString(Cursor cur) {
            int index = cur.getColumnIndex(FieldInstallationDB.ITEM_NAME);
            return cur.getString(index);
        }});
    equipment.setAdapter(itemNameAdapter);
```

Here is the suggestitemcompletions method written in the activity class:

```
public Cursor suggestItemCompletions(CharSequence str) {

    return getContentResolver().query(null, new String[] {FieldInstallationDB.ITEM_NAME}, "(" + FieldInstallationDB.ITEM_NAME + " LIKE ? ", new String[] {"%" + str + "%"}, null);

}
```

This suggests to use getContentResolver() which does not make sense in my case since I am accessing the database of my application and not of another application. As a result it does not work because I set the URI parameter to null since my database table has no URI. However, if i decide not to use getContentResolver() and query the FieldInstallationDB directly, I get the error at .query() saying cannot resolve method.

**UPDATE II:**

I used rawQuery() as suggested and it works:

```
public Cursor suggestItemCompletions(CharSequence str) {
    fieldInstDatabase = openForRead();
    String sql = "Select "+ ITEM_NAME+ " FROM "+ TABLE_EQUIPMENT+ " WHERE "+ ITEM_NAME + " LIKE ?";
    String[]  selectArgs = new String[]{ "%" + str + "%"};

    return fieldInstDatabase.rawQuery(sql,selectArgs);

}
```

This method is in my db class and I am calling it in main activity here:

```
itemNameAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {

        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
            return sqlitedb1.suggestItemCompletions(constraint);
        }
    });
```

This is working except that I am getting an IllegalArgumentException here:

> 01-10 13:07:08.792 5361-5361/com.example.sweetiean.stlfieldinstallation1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                              Process: com.example.sweetiean.stlfieldinstallation1, PID: 5361
>                                                                                              java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'Bag(TypeC) : 
>                                                                                              5900016009' does not exist

which makes sense because "Bag(TypeC) : 
                                                                                     5900016009" is not a column, it is the first item in the ITEM NAME column in the database.

I do not know why it is reading the first item as the column name. I have tried to debug but I cannot step into

```
public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
        return sqlitedb1.suggestItemCompletions(constraint);
    }
```

Comment: use `SimpleCursorAdapter` and setup its `FilterQueryProvider` like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19860624/2252830), do not use `ArrayAdapter`, of course you need to return your database `Cursor` from `runQuery` method

Comment: @pskink this put me in the right direction however, I have ran into a few more problems to which I will update my question

Comment: call `sqlitedb.rawQuery`

Comment: @pskink kindly assist with update 2

Comment: see the `from` and `to` parameters of `SimpleCursorAdapter` constructor

Comment: I debugged again and `results.count = cursor.getCount();` in CursorFilter.java returns the right count. What exactly should I look out for in those parameters @pskink

Comment: see what i am passing as those parameters

Comment: @pskink see them where? I don't see your update to the question.

Comment: see the link in my first comment above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132810/discussion-between-sweetie-anang-and-pskink).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, an IllegalArgumentException is occurring here because of the `from` parameter in my SimpleCursorAdapter. The `from` and `to` parameters of the SimpleCursorAdapter require the column name of the table and the textview to populate respectively.

In my case, I was populating the `from` parameter with a string array of the items I was getting from the database:

```
String[] items = sqlitedb1.getAllItemNames();

for(int i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
{
    Log.i(this.toString(), items[i]);
}

equipment.setThreshold(1);


SimpleCursorAdapter itemNameAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
        this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, null, items, toView, 0);
```

Correcting it to:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter itemNameAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
        this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, null, fromCol, toView, 0);
```

With `fromCol` defined as `final static String[] fromCol = new String[] { FieldInstallationDB.ITEM_NAME };` fixed it.